# How do I get rid of this weird white background on my list view

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface

I'm trying to make an Android version of my iOS app and I'm getting this weird white border around my list view and around my images on the list view that's super frustrating. Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Here's my code for the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.leoconnelly.connexus.HealthCenterListActivity">

android:background="#D53D96"

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/hospitals_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="#D53D96"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove android:layout_margin="8dp"

Answer (score 0):

You can delete `android:layout_margin="8dp"` from `ListView` or put the same background into it parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#D53D96"
tools:context="com.example.leoconnelly.connexus.HealthCenterListActivity">



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/hospitals_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="#D53D96"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```